# What is wrong in this 'for loop' in R? Please see

Tags: r, for-loop

```
z=c("abcD9","recde6","7gfbe","dvS1","MNM09")
d=c("abcD9","recde6","abcD9","bgfh123","dvS1")
y <- numeric(length=25)
k<-1
for ( i in 1:5) {
  for (j in  1:5) {
    a <- (z[i]==d[j])
    if( a==TRUE) y[k] <- j else y[k] <- 0
  }
  k<-k+1
}
```

I should get the result as
'y' as a vector (1 0 3 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0)

Comment: I added some indendation to your code, this makes it much more readable imo.

Comment: You might want to look at the output for `outer( d,z,"==")` and see if it helps you use R's vectorization features more fully.

Comment: 3 great answers here. Are none of them worth accepting so this question does not appear unasnwered? If not, please say why not. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for a more vectorized/apply loop approach:

```
y = do.call('c', lapply(z, function(x) ifelse(x == d, seq_along(d), 0)))
[1] 1 0 3 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0
```

or using `expand.grid`:

```
df = data.frame(expand.grid(d = d, z = z, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
                y = rep(seq_along(d), length(z)))
with(df, ifelse(z == d, y, 0))
```

Comment: +1 nice to see an approach to eliminate the unnecessary loops (in this example, because execution speed of the loop iterations is so fast)

Comment: And the code is shorter, more expressive, less imperative, more functional, more R-like.

Answer (score 3):

You could eliminate the loop and do something vectorised like so:

```
pos <- t( outer( z , d , FUN = "==" ) )
pos[ pos == TRUE ] <- which( pos , arr.ind = TRUE )[,1]
as.vector(pos)
#[1] 1 0 3 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Agree this appears most elegant. Mine was going to be:  `c( ifelse(outer( d,z,"=="), row(outer( d,z,"==")), 0 ) )`, but this appears equally nice.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you move `k<-k+1` into the inner loop:

```
for ( i in 1:5)
{
  for (j in  1:5)
  {
    a <- (z[i]==d[j])
    if( a==TRUE)
      y[k] <- j
    else
      y[k] <- 0
    k<-k+1  
  }  
}
```

The result (`y`):

```
[1] 1 0 3 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

By the way: You can obtain the same result with the following commands:

```
tmp <- sapply(z, function(vec1) !is.na(match(d, vec1)))
y <- numeric(length = length(tmp))
y[unlist(tmp)] <- which(tmp, arr.ind = TRUE)[ , 1]
```